# Why hosts have routing tables?

Tags: routing, switch, layer3, route-table

I don't understand why hosts in a network have a routing table. Aren't all packets sent by default to the switch, and the latter determines which port to forward the packet to based on the mac address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do all network devices need to make routing decisions, regardless of communication across networks or within a network?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58051/do-all-network-devices-need-to-make-routing-decisions-regardless-of-communicati).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosts can have multiple interfaces to different networks (in fact, they have a loopback network too), and the routing table tells the network stack which interface to use for a network.

Even with a single network interface, there could be multiple gateways on that network that may be used for different destination networks.

Comment: Even if the host has multiple interfaces it still forwards all of its packet to the switch, who decides which device to forward the packet to based on the specified destination mac address written on the packet. So I don't see the utility behind implementing a routing table for network hosts.

Comment: Which switch? Each interface could be connected to a different switch and each use a different network. The host cannot guess (routing is deterministic), and it must know to which interface it must send the packet based on the destination address. Even one interface could have multiple routers with different destinations, and the routing table will tell the host to which destination router layer-2 it should build the frame for the packet.

Comment: But why do we need to add the default gateway to the routing table of the host even in cases where there is only one interface, one switch, and one router?

Comment: The default gateway is the gateway of last resort. The most specific route is used, and a default route is the least specific route. The default route gets used if there is no more specific route to the destination network. You can have multiple routers with more specific routes to some networks, but any destination not matching those destinations go to the default gateway.

Comment: From what I understand, the routing table is only used to specify the interface through which the packet is going to be sent, not the last node that will receive the packet in the [local] network. If there is only one interface and one router, adding the default gateway to the routing table of the host would be of no additional use in determining the [unique] interface through which packets destined outside the network are going to be sent.

Comment: "_From what I understand, the routing table is only used to specify the interface through which the packet is going to be sent_" No. A host forwards packets destined to a different network to a gateway (router). It does that by putting the gateway layer-2 address on the layer-2 frame it builds to encapsulate an IP packet. The routing table will tell the host to which gateway it should send the frame.

Comment: _"The routing table will tell the host to which gateway it should send the frame"_ Doesn't the host already have information pertaining to the default gateway(s) that it has? To know which gateway it should send the frame it could compare the destination IP address to its different IP addresses using the corresponding subnet masks, and look up the IP address of the default gateway associated with the one that matches?

Comment: The default gateway is the gateway of last resort. Any other gateways need configuration. Based on your questions, I think you are looking at this from the perspective of a home user. Business networking can get quite complex, which is the reason for network engineering. At work, I have multiple gateways that can be used for different networks to get a more direct path for those networks.

Comment: And the default gateway specification only exists in the routing table?

Comment: A default route may be in the routing table, and the gateway to which it points is the default gateway. It is not even necessary to have a default route, especially if there is no Internet access. You may only have specific routes pointing to one or more gateways. A default route is really a requirement for using the public Internet because there are so many destinations there it is impractical to put them all in your routing table (Internet routers may have that, but there are hundreds of thousands of routes on the public Internet).